# Accessing DLL from ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently trying to redesign a web page written in Asp.net and C#. I have created some classes that will be used in the codebehind file (written in C#). I have added reference to the dll file of the classes I have created. Dll files are all located in the Bin directory.

However, when I tried to access the page the following error is displayed.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'xxxxxx'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I am including the dll namespace by using "using ;".

```
using MyNamespace;
```

Is there some kind of settings that needs to be done to access the classes in the dll file?

- I am using .net 1.1 framework

Thanks,
artsylar

Comment: What is the framework used for creating dll, is it .Net 1.1 ? also how did you add the reference in the project ?

Comment: try to create an instance to use the dll

Comment: @Habib, I used Visual Studio 2010 so I can only set the target framework to 2.0.

Comment: @patrickchoi I am sorry but would you mind explaining it?

Comment: You **cannot** use a .NET 2.0 DLL in a .NET 1.1 program, directly. You would need to expose it via Interop, have .NET 2.0 installed on that server, and consume it via Interop. (Yes - you'd be going two-ways via Interop)

Comment: @AndrewBarber yes you're right. I've recompiled my library in VS 2008 and set the target framework to 1.1. I have also added assemblies entry in my web.config and it works!

Comment: @artsylar, VS2008 does not support .NET 1.1, only 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5.

Comment: @David yes it doesn't but if you add a customized target then you can build a library for .net 1.1. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2005/04/22/410903.aspx)

Comment: Seems like a bit of a hack. Why not just install VS2003? Multiple versions of VS can co-exist fine.

Comment: @David, thanks for the suggestion but We don't have VS 2003 only VS 2010. And there's no express edition available for VS 2003.

Comment: "downgrade rights" might apply in your situation. Have you tried building your project using the command-line CSC in .Net 1.1?

Comment: thanks @Dai! I've just found another option which is using MSBee (http://msbee.codeplex.com/) on VS 2005 express project file. I'll also try your suggestion. thanks again @Dai

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include any third-party DLL used by your class library DLL .
The name 'xxxxxx' should be indicator for the missed DLL that contains the type .